# rendererPane becomes null while using BasicTableUI from swing

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jtable, nullpointerexception

I am using a JTable, and I get a null pointer exception at random times while updating it. When I set Eclipse to catch all null pointer exceptions, I was very surprised to see the rendererPane field in BasicTableUI.java (a Swing class) is null. Has anyone had to deal with this before? I am lost on how to tackle this issue.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) but first make sure that all GUI updates are made on the EDT.

Comment: for why hells on this world you tried to use BasicTableUI, sure as Andrew commented edit your question with a SSCCE,

Comment: _while updating it ..._  make sure this happens on the EDT. The `NullPointer` you catch is most likely a side-effect of accessing/altering Swing components on another Thread then the EDT

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic error, I was running Swing code outside the EDT, thanks for reminding me to check that out!